# Filtering Out Data Returned by an API by Date

Tags: php

I have data returned by an API that I'm looping through and populating a table with. I'm only interested in the data that is from the last thirty days.

I've written some code that takes today's date, subtracts 30 days from it and stores the result. It then creates a new array, loops through the API data and compares the date of each entry, disregarding anything that falls outside the boundaries.

```php
      $response = curl_exec($curl);
      $err = curl_error($curl);
      $responseResult = json_decode($response, true);
      curl_close($curl);

      if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {

        $today = date('Y-m-j');
        $newdate = strtotime ( '-30 days' , strtotime ( $today ) ) ;
        $newdate = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $newdate );

        foreach($responseResult as $subject) {
            $createdDate = $subject['created_at'];
            if($createdDate < $newdate) {
                $filteredThirtyDays[] = $createdDate;
            }
        }
        
        return count($filteredThirtyDays);
```

This doesn't work. My logic is wrong.

#### Sample Data

```php
 {
        "id": "5cf65651bbddbd5462599808",
        "number": 4551,
        "user_id": "5b8425c8e694aa3c6a835b67",
        "state": "closed",
        "subject": "Database",
        "label_ids": [
            "5c49b2d9bbddbd17834bbff6"
        ],
        "customer_id": "5b52f0cabbddbd01c5bdd6c8",
        "type": "email",
        "reply_to": "user@domain.com",
        "reply_cc": "",
        "group_id": "5a5f65fed5593070120b9779",
        "inbox_id": "5a5f65fed5593070120b9779",
        "updated_at": "2019-06-04T13:41:58Z",
        "created_at": "2019-06-04T11:30:25Z",
        "spam": false,
        "trash": false,
        "summary": "",
        "rating": null,
        "waiting_since": "2019-06-04T12:56:05Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "5cf6561ebbddbd28217a0b89",
        "number": 4550,
        "user_id": "5b51bf13bbddbd7e6248c934",
        "state": "closed",
        "subject": "Exchange",
        "label_ids": [
            "5c4b0cf4bbddbd48cd69e68a"
        ],
        "customer_id": "5b51fdf1bbddbd5f4575a428",
        "type": "phone",
        "reply_to": "user@domain.com",
        "reply_cc": "",
        "group_id": "5a5f65fed5593070120b9779",
        "inbox_id": "5a5f65fed5593070120b9779",
        "updated_at": "2019-06-04T12:49:06Z",
        "created_at": "2019-06-04T11:29:35Z",
        "spam": false,
        "trash": false,
        "summary": "Hi Chris Might have been the user name",
        "rating": null,
        "waiting_since": "2019-06-04T12:41:08Z"
    }
]
```

What I want is a count of how many items are within the thirty day period. What I'm getting is all results from all dates.

### EDIT :

I THINK the issue is the time format. The API is returning the date as a string, formatted as **2019-06-04T12:49:06Z**. When I do **echo strtotime('2019-06-04T12:49:06Z');** it returns **1559652546**, which is what is being compared.

So, I think I need to convert the Zulu time format into something I can use to compare...

Comment: Can you show us a few example occurances from `$responseResult`

Comment: Did you convert that from a JSON String into an array of objects before attempting to process it?

Comment: Which date do you want to compare against? `updated_at` or `created_at` because there is no field in there called just `date` ???

Comment: **created_at** is what I'm after. I've tried **$responseResult['created_at']** in the loop, but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: `if ($date < strtotime('-30 days'))` should be enough to get what you are looking for

Comment: @AnandG Tried this, it produces a zero value. I've modified the code above and changed the loop.

Comment: In the given API response, I do not see any data which can fall in last 30 days, is there any?

Comment: @AnandG Yes, I can't post the full dataset as there is confidential info I'd have to filter out and there are 100 results. The issue was the Zulu timestamp. I had to first convert that from a string and then perform the comparison. Schoolboy error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this works for your.

```
<? php
$responseResult = '[{
"id" : "5cf65651bbddbd5462599808",
"number": 4551,
"user_id": "5b8425c8e694aa3c6a835b67",
"state": "closed",
"subject": "Database",
"label_ids": [
  "5c49b2d9bbddbd17834bbff6"
],
"customer_id": "5b52f0cabbddbd01c5bdd6c8",
"type": "email",
"reply_to": "user@domain.com",
"reply_cc": "",
"group_id": "5a5f65fed5593070120b9779",
"inbox_id": "5a5f65fed5593070120b9779",
"updated_at": "2019-06-04T13:41:58Z",
"created_at": "2019-06-04T11:30:25Z",
"spam": false,
"trash": false,
"summary": "",
"rating": null,
"waiting_since": "2019-06-04T12:56:05Z"
}, {
  "id": "5cf6561ebbddbd28217a0b89",
  "number": 4550,
  "user_id": "5b51bf13bbddbd7e6248c934",
  "state": "closed",
  "subject": "Exchange",
  "label_ids": [
    "5c4b0cf4bbddbd48cd69e68a"
  ],
  "customer_id": "5b51fdf1bbddbd5f4575a428",
  "type": "phone",
  "reply_to": "user@domain.com",
  "reply_cc": "",
  "group_id": "5a5f65fed5593070120b9779",
  "inbox_id": "5a5f65fed5593070120b9779",
  "updated_at": "2019-06-04T12:49:06Z",
  "created_at": "2019-05-04T11:29:35Z",
  "spam": false,
  "trash": false,
  "summary": "Hi Chris Might have been the user name",
  "rating": null,
  "waiting_since": "2019-06-04T12:41:08Z"
}]
';

$today = date('Y-m-j');
$filteredThirtyDays = array();
$responseResultArr = json_decode($responseResult);
foreach($responseResultArr as $created => $date) {
  $nDate = (array) $date;

  if (strtotime($nDate['created_at']) <= strtotime('-30 days')) {
    $filteredThirtyDays[] = $date;
  }
}

print_r($filteredThirtyDays);
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! Your first response was correct, I just needed to convert the string first before it would work.